# Does this "filtering" function exist? What would be a good name for such a function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, naming-conventions

I'm solving a Project Euler problem which involves all the n-digit numbers with a certain property. It seems that the easiest way to get them might be to get a list of all the numbers with that property (which would be infinitely long), then select out the ones with the right number of digits. Like this:

```
numsWithCoolProperty = filter hasCoolProperty [1..]

nDigitNumsWithCoolProperty n = takeWhile (< 10^n) $ dropWhile (<= 10^(n-1)) numsWithOtherCoolProperty
```

But now if I want to do the same thing with a different property, I'll be repeating myself:

```
nDigitNumsWithOtherCoolProperty n = takeWhile (< 10^n) $ dropWhile (<= 10^(n-1)) numsWithOtherCoolProperty
```

so I want a function that captures the dropWhile/takeWhile logic. Something like:

```
f :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
f pred = takeWhile pred . dropWhile (not . pred)
```

and then if I have a predicate `hasNDigits n m` which returns true if m has n digits, I can do:

```
nDigitNumsWithCoolProperty n = f (hasNDigits n) numsWithCoolProperty
nDigitNumsWithOtherCoolProperty n = f (hasNDigits n) numsWithOtherCoolProperty
```

Anyway, my question is about the function `f` which has the same type as dropWhile and takeWhile: Does it already exist somewhere? If not, what would be a good name for it? All I can think of is something like `dropUntilTakeWhile` but I'm sure there's a better name out there.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make `take until + drop while` recursive?  Otherwise it would only work on a single transition between predicate matches and non-predicate matches.  (I don't know the syntax well at all, so I can't tell if your definition of `f` already does this)

Comment: In this particular case, I know that `numsWithCoolProperty` is sorted (I guess I should have said that) which means I know all the three digit numbers will be grouped together. When it switches from two-digit to three-digit numbers, I want to start including those, and when it switches from three-digit to four-digit, I want to stop. If I didn't know the list was sorted (or that all the numbers matching the predicate were grouped in a single run) then I would use `filter`. But I can't do that here because it's an infinite list, and I want to get a finite one back.

Comment: Not that helpful, but you might call it `takeRange`, and call the predicate `isInRange`

Comment: How about a different approach: `nDigitNums n = [10^(n-1)..10^n-1]` and then filter on that.

Comment: I would call that function simply `dropTakeWhile`.

Comment: @hammar I think that's probably a good approach, at least for some problems. I don't know if you've done any Project Euler, but it seems like lots of the problems involve finding all the numbers that fit two different properties. Often one of the challenges is determining whether to get all the property1 numbers, and then filter on whether they have property2, or vice versa. Hard to know which way is better without lots of analysis, or just good old profiling

Comment: @MatrixFrog: I've done quite a few. Most of the time there's a way to construct the numbers directly, rather than just filter for them. For example you can often build up the numbers by digits, factors, or some recurrence.

Answer (score 7):

Your function:

```
f pred = takeWhile pred . dropWhile (not . pred)
```

Is strongly related to the `span` and `break` functions, as you can see:

```
span  :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a]) 

break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Let's see some examples:

```
> span (< 3) [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
([1,2],[3,4,1,2,3,4])

> break (< 3) [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
([],[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4])
```

and your function:

```
> f (< 3) [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
[1,2]
```

Now, we have one law relating `span` to `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`,

> `span` *p xs* is equivalent to
>   *(`takeWhile` p xs, `dropWhile` p xs)*

so we might consider your function part of the `span` and `break` group of functions. It is also related to lexing, where you gather some token that matches a predicate.

So, you might call this function `gather` or `lex` or something similar.